# React with SASS is removing the CSS page size parameter

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, size

I have some JSX in a react component I am wanting to create a modular document (only A4 output). When I look at the chrome inspector the "size" attribute has not seemed to make it into the final CSS I am using SCSS

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PageContainer/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

with the component

```
export default function PageContainer() {
  return (


    <page size="A4">fdsaffdsa fdsafdsafdsa fdsa fdsa fds </page>
  );
}
```

and CSS

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}
page[size="A3"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 42cm;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<page>` tag or `size` attribute that React recognizes.

What you can do is add a custom `data-size` attribute and change your CSS to use the custom attribute.

I also recommend you to use `div` instead of `page`.

Something like this:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
.page {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.page[data-size="A4"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
.page[data-size="A4"][data-layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}
.page[data-size="A3"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 42cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" data-size="A4">fdsaffdsa fdsafdsafdsa fdsa fdsa fds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` has a notion of paged media. You can do something like:

```
@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;
}
```

If you are trying to print. Then you can try this.

```
@media print {
    body{
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
        margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;
   } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.